# How does pigeonhole principle imply that $|\theta_k-\theta_j|\leq 2\pi/N<\delta$ where $\theta_k=(k\theta)\mod 2\pi$

Tags: pigeonhole-principle, quantum-computation

[image]

I am trying to understand this part from the book [Page 196, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielsen and Chuang](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf).

Here $R_{\hat{n}}(\theta)=\cos(\theta/2)I-i(\hat{n}.\vec{\sigma})\sin(\theta/2)$ and $\theta$ is defined such that $\cos(\theta/2)=\cos^2(\pi/8)$ and therefore $\theta$ can be shown to be an irrational multiple of $2\pi$.

So, in the statement we are taking, the desired accuracy as $\delta>0$, an integer $N$ is chosen such that $\delta>\frac{2\pi}{N}$.

Defining $\theta_k$ so that $\theta_k\in[0,2\pi)$ and $\theta_k=(k\theta)\mod 2\pi$, i.e., $k\theta=2\pi t+\theta_k$.

How do I make sense of the rest of the statement ?

How does pigeonhole principle implies that $|\theta_k-\theta_j|\leq 2\pi/N<\delta$ for some distinct integers $j,k\in 1,2,\cdots,N$ ?

**Pigeonhole Principle Definitions**

1. If n objects are distributed over m places, and if n > m, then some place receives at least two objects.
   equivalently, if n objects are distributed over n places in such a way that no place receives more than one object, then each place receives exactly one object.
2. If n objects are distributed over m places, and if n < m, then some place receives no object.
   equivalently, If n objects are distributed over n places in such a way that no place receives no object, then each place receives exactly one object.

Can I make use of this definition to prove $|\theta_k-\theta_j|\leq 2\pi/N$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you need $N+1$ values. Separate $[0,2\pi)$ into $N$ bins of equal length $2\pi/N$, so
$$ I_i = [2\pi (i-1)/N, 2\pi i/N)$$
for $1 \leq i \leq N$. By the pigeon hole principle we’d then get two $\theta_k,\theta_l$ in the same bin.

If we take $[0,1)$ instead of $[0,2\pi)$ we might for example have $\theta_1=1/10$, $\theta_2=9/10$ and the distance is clearly bigger than $1/2$. So you’d need $N+1=3$ points for this to work.

Comment: That being said: If you take the distance on the circle (so wrapped around) instead, you only need $N$ points. That is easy to see: Assume that $\theta_k$ are sorted. Then we can assume $\theta_1=0$ (because we can rotate (i.e. subtract $\theta_1$) all points on the circle without changing distance). Then assume $k_{j+1}-k_j>2\pi/N$ for all $<\leq j < N$. Then $\theta_N > (N-1)2\pi/N$. But this means that $\theta_1+2\pi - \theta_N = 2\pi-\theta_N < 2\pi (1-(N-1))/N = 2\pi/N$.

Comment: in tha last line in your comment, $\theta_1+2\pi-\theta_N=2\pi-\theta_N<2\pi-(N-1)\frac{2\pi}{N}=2\pi\frac{(1-N+1)}{N}=\frac{2\pi}{N}(2-N)<\frac{2\pi}{N}$, for $N>2$ right ?

Comment: @SoorajS No, the last line is a typo, it should have been
$$ 2\pi-\theta_N < 2\pi(N-(N-1))/N$$

Comment: $2\pi-(N-1)2\pi/N = 2\pi(1-(N-1)/N)$ and quite obviously we have $1-(N-1)/N=1/N$.

Comment: Also $1-(N-1)/N = (N-(N-1))/N$.

Answer (score 1):

Due to irrationality, you won’t hit $2\pi$ for any $\theta_j$ with $1\leq j\leq N$ so there will be no repeats in the $\theta_j$ values.

By pigeonhole, the $\theta_j$ split the unit circle into $N$ subintervals whose boundaries are the $\theta_j$ values. They are are most spread apart when they are equally distributed on the circle. Thus at least two $\theta_i,\theta_j$ are at most $2\pi/N$ radians apart in absolute difference, at the two endpoints of the shortest interval.

Comment: Here, we can define $N$ number of $\theta_k$'s $\in [0,2\pi)$ from the definition $k\theta=2\pi t_k+\theta_k$ and $\theta_k$ is an irrational multiple of $2\pi$, and also consequently $\theta_k$ never touches $2\pi$. And, pigeonhole principle states that if $n$ items are put into $m$ places with $n>m$ then at least one place must contain more than one item. How does this definition affect the distribution ? Could you please elaborate on that ?

Comment: Though, logically it makes sense to that the $\theta_k$'s are most spread apart when they are equally distributed on the circle, i.e., $2\pi /N$ interval. That, means if one pair $\theta_k,\theta_j$ is more than $2\pi /N$ apart, then there exists another $\theta_i$ wich is less than $2\pi /N$ apart with either $\theta_k$ or $\theta_j$.